# How to trace variable values when using os.system() or using `subprocess.run()` to run python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to trace variable values  using `sys.settrace()` when using `os.system()` or using `subprocess.run()` to run python file?

My current implementation goes like this:

```
sys.settrace(traceit)
os.system(f"python {fname} < {inp_fp}")
sys.settrace(None)
```

But I am getting no traces at all, any clue?

Comment: What variables? The subprocess has no access to variables in the parent process.

Comment: thanks @tripleee how about os.system?

Comment: `os.system()` runs the command in a subprocess.

Comment: thanks @Barmar, any idea how to get variable traces at all when running an external python file?

Comment: A much better solution anyhow is to `import` the code and run it within the current process. You may have to refactor it slightly to be able to do that.

Comment: Even if you could enable tracing in the external python process, it wouldn't be able to call your `traceit` function in the current process.

Comment: thanks @tripleee the thing is the python files use input(), and I should not edit those files in anyway, there are many of them too..

Comment: Sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and even more reason to refactor those scripts.

Comment: thanks @Barmar and @tripleee, how can I refactor and pass inputs to those files that use `input()`while I cannot change them? Also since IDE's already store variables, do you think I can access those in any way?

Comment: Use `subprocess.run()` and redirect the subprocess's `stdin` to the data you want to pass. If it's more interactive, use `pexpect` to control it.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar is it possible to trace variable values using pexpect?

Comment: No, it's just for emulating the user when controlling the program. There's no way to trace variables in another process, it has to be done in that process itself.